# GUI quite unresponsive with 4 textboxes and combobox

Tags: c#, user-interface

a lurker here, but time for my own question.
The question applies to this code: http://pastebin.com/dQKnSSpY I posted it on pastebin because it'll mess up this page otherwise :)

my question is why the GUI is quite lagging when I run this GUI. I've already tried several things, including DoubleBuffering, a seperate workerthread for adding the Controls and using BindingSource.
Nothing helped yet. I'm feeling a bit dumb, because usually my C# skills are okayish. (quite new to Windows Forms)

thanks in advance

Comment: Was part of that code auto generated or is this all from scratch?

Comment: everything is from scratch. I like that better because you have more control over your boxes I find

Comment: Thats good, I've made an answer which may help.

Comment: Updated my pastebin to try and take into account what jure said. Take a look.

Comment: Also I will add that although it can be good to learn from scratch you might be best making the forms in the IDE designer like visual Studio to get the best results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you are creating controls inside Paint event. I'm little rusty now in Windows Forms, but i think Paint event is called when the control needs to redraw itself and that is controlled by the OS with WM_PAINT message. And that can happen frequently. Maybe you should try to add controls in the Form constructor and not in the Paint event.

Comment: I'm with you with being rusty in Forms. What should I leave in the paint methods then. Only the this.Controls.Add(), or...?

Comment: I would say nothing. Don't even subscribe to that event. Paint is only needed if you have some custom painting logic. Adding controls is not paint logic, WinForms will paint that for you. You would need Paint if lets say you neead a nice colorful ellipse or circle or something like that on your form.

Comment: you, my dear sir, are very correct. When I just call the methods in the constructor and nothing else, the GUI works flawless. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple change but it may help:

http://pastebin.com/FnXJCAUE

I took the `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` calculations out of your GUI updates and replaced them with a constant Integer that is calculated only once at the initialisation of GUI Class. This should help reduce the number of calculations performed each GUI draw and so speed up drawing in general, elsewise I didn't see anything immediately obvious in the code that would slow things down.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately it doesn't help much, if anything at all :( if I type some numbers in the textboxes in my GUI, it goes real slow, with a single processor of my laptop (a modern one) running at around 80%.

Comment: In which case I adjusted it would look at @jure 's approach. I removed the paint events as this should be handled by the forms object already and made the controls add themselves to the form on the initialise, I have no idea if this is working but debug it and try it out